# Antonym of "deficiency"

Tags: antonyms

The context in which we use word "deficiency" is inspection. Let's say, I look at your gas furnace and file a deficiency report describing some component or part.

What would the opposite of "deficiency" in this context? What would I call the "report" that certifies that your gas furnace is working well?

Thanks!

Comment: Verification, validation, certification, pass, etc.

Comment: I think "validation" works best in this situation... Thanks!

Comment: Logically, one obvious candidate is  _sufficiency_, but that wouldn't work here. Even _adequacy_ sounds pejorative, and _satisfactoriness_ cheesy.

Comment: Or, you could say that if there isn't a fault then there's no need to file a report! There's already too much paperwork in the world....................zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: If the inspection covers multiple criteria, on each of which the inspector rates a unit's performance as "adequate"/"inadequate," "sufficient"/"insufficient," "acceptable"/"unacceptable," or the like, I think the problem lies in labeling one of the categories _deficiencies_ and looking for an antonym of that term. Why not use the column heading "Feature" or "Function" or "Item" for the column containing the list of inspection criteria, and then use one of the pairs of descriptive adjectives noted above as the column heads for columns of "approved" and "disapproved" check marks?

Answer (score 2):

A Deficiency Report.

A Notice of Compliance ?

Comment: mmmm... not quite. imagine you hold a Home Inspection report, there's "Deficiencies" section, and then... what? What would you call the section that asserts that all items inspected below passed the inspection?

Comment: Yes, this is surely the answer. Of course, _compliance_ and _deficiency_ are hardly antonyms.

Comment: @temun This **is** the answer to your' What would I call the "report" that certifies that your gas furnace is working well?' If you mean 'entry', that is the term to use.

Comment: Yes, technically. If you think of "deficiency" as a "report". Then you'd have "Deficiency Report" and "Compliance Report". But this is not what I am after. I need a direct antonym of word "deficiency", so I could build a tabbable User Interface with "Deficiencies" and "....?" tabs side by side. "Notice of Compliance" or "Compliance(s)" hardly works there.

Comment: Maybe I should've asked the question differently. Apologies for that.

Comment: well, @temuri I thought of the direct antonym in the beginning, which would be ***"adequacy"*** or ***"sufficiency"***. Nevertheless, I deleted my answer after i saw Daniels answer and Edwins just comment that they do not really fit your needs/ your question.

Answer (score 1):

For home inspections, the opposite of "deficiency" might vary from "barely satisfactory" to "state of the art". To simplify an approval rating, one might title the column "approved" or, to comply with legal issues, **"up to code"**.

Comment: +1 _satisfactory_, but not "barely"; [satisfactory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satisfactory) can be _fulfilling all demands or requirements_ per se. Either it's subpar or on par with the standards as you allude to.

Answer (score 0):

After a thorough examination, your gas furnace was found to be...

- **"in compliance with** current regulations".
- **"free of defects"**.
- "**in accordance with** current legislation."

> Edit.
>   compliance (noun) the act or process of doing what you have been asked or ordered to do : the act or process of complying.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the suggestions are nouns..

Comment: @temuri I thought you wanted a phrase for "working well". Can you write a sentence and leave blanks for the word you are looking for?

Comment: Perhaps you could let go of the word deficiency (it sounds rather grand for the purpose you are describing) and just use pass or fail for your tabbable user interface ...

Comment: @temuri: ***Compliance*** is a noun (the state of complying). The adjective is ***compliant*** (meets the required standard).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, given your elaboration in the comments, I think I see what you're requesting now: a title for a category of statements/fields in a software interface, to complement "deficiencies" and to mean "things which have not been found to be deficient during this inspection".

In that case, I would use a term like **approvals**, as the inspector is clearly either *approving* of some feature or is marking it as a deficiency.  It's not strictly speaking an antonym, as approval implies a person making a value judgment while deficiency implies a problem regardless of the presence of a person, but it seems to be the type of word you're looking for here.